# How to limit static electricity on my new seed sieve?

Tags: seeds, tools, seed-saving

I just made the mistake of purchasing a plastic seed sieve.  I've only used it a couple of times, and already regret not purchasing a larger metal one - but they were so much more expensive. I've decided to give it a go and call it a learning experience.

My biggest problem is that there's a lot of static electricity that builds up on the plastic and the both the seeds and chaff stick to it.  Any tricks to preventing this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

An ionizer might help neutralise static charges building up on plastic surfaces but this sounds uneconomic. You can't drain static from a plastic surface to ground.  You need to replace with a metal sieve.

https://www.electrostatics.com/staticelectricity.html